# Mac Mail not including original email headers in Reply

Tags: mail.app

Is there any way to make Mail include the to/cc email addresses when forwarding/responding to a message? currently all I get is:

```
On Oct 15, 2013, at 2:47 PM, John Doe <jDoe@jDoe.com> wrote:
```

what I would like is:

```
From: Dakine83 
Sent: Tuesday, October 15, 2013 2:55 PM
To: John Doe
Cc: Jane Doe
Subject: Re: Clean the fridge!
```

Not including who has seen the email chain is a serious omission, hopefully it's just a setting I can't find.

Comment: Any update for macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't customize the Reply/Forward headers without the help of [QuoteFix](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40735/quotefix) or [ReplyWithHeader](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/49256/replywithheader).

To customize the actual headers when viewing an email message, I'll quote [this](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57360674-263/get-mail-to-show-the-right-e-mail-header-details/) MacFixIt article:

> To alter the headers that Mail includes, you can go to the Viewing section of the Mail preferences, choose the Custom setting, and then add or remove any fields of the e-mail header that you wish to see. Unfortunately you need to enter the field names manually, and many times e-mail services will append their own header details to a message, especially for handling spam or other security features. Therefore if you are not sure what the header titles are then you will need look them up in the raw source code for any particular message.
>
> To do this, select a message in your inbox and then press Option-Command-U or choose "Raw Source" from the View > Message menu. In the resulting window you will see all the message details in plain text. Header fields will be the text before colon characters with dashes in them in place of spaces, and may include items like "Delivered-to:" or "Return-Path:", or custom items like "X-Virus-Scanned:" for antivirus information.
>
> When entering these details in the custom headers list, be sure to enter them as is (including the dashes), after which be sure that Custom is selected in the preferences and that the Details link is clicked in your e-mail messages.

[image: MailHeaderCustomSettings]

Comment: Considering Apples slant towards the corporate world lately... this is ridiculous. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems that both QuoteFix and ReplyWithHeader cannot work on big sur. It weird that Apple has not added this long-waited functionality in its native app.